# Powershell jobs, scriptblock and exe program flags

Tags: windows, powershell

I wanted to run two tasks from one Powershell, and I'm grateful to a member providing me with an answer. For simplicity, they used/copied the Start-Sleep routine I'd quoted. I thought it would be a simple case of replacing said routine with a link to the required script. How wrong can you be ??

So to run a program in the background whilst a progressbar marquee runs in the original process, they used "jobs" and "ScriptBlock" ... but I found that cannot handle variables and flags directly ... which is why I am now stumped (AGAIN! For the THIRD time!) I think the answer lies in $ARGS(x) and -ArgumentList, but have got no further.

Here is the "interesting" command that needs to run as a background job.

```
& $outpath -i $file -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 $saveOut -nostats -loglevel warning;
=== MY_DiRECTORY\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe -i $file -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 $saveOut -nostats -loglevel warning
```

** Copied from the line that works when run as a single thread script. (It takes about 20 secs to run, hence the reason I wanted to add the progress bar to show it hasn't stalled)

As you can see, not only have I got to pass "$outpath", "$file" and "$saveOut" to the background job, (which may need to go into a param{} area) there are also numerous other flags and words that have got to be carried over and 'executed' as one line. Incidentally, $outpath is created dynamically, and $file /$saveOut come from user entered fields via standard Windows dialogues

I love making things complicated (although it's probably "schoolboy stuff" to the more knowledgable) !!

If the original person picks up on this (js****er) I'm having to post these as "Guest", so do not have access to other features such as forums. When I log in to my normal account, I cannot ask questions, and with a 15 reputation, votes do not appear.

++++ UPDATE 14th AUGUST+++++

After =A LOT= of trial and error, I eventually came up with this code:

```
$ArguementList='-i "{0}" -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 "{1}" -loglevel quiet -stats' -f $file, $saveOut

    $ProgressBar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
    $ProgressBar.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 35)
    $ProgressBar.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(460, 40)
    $ProgressBar.Style = "Marquee"
    $ProgressBar.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 20

    $main_form.Controls.Add($ProgressBar);

    $V2ALabel.Font = $procFont
    $V2ALabel.ForeColor = 'red'
    $V2ALabel.Text = "Processing ..."

$process=Start-Process -filePath "$ScriptDir\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe" $ArguementList -PassThru -WindowStyle hidden

do{
 [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
}
until ($process.ExitCode -eq 0)
```

I'm not saying this as fact, (only based on my trials), but it seems that FFMPEG on Windows HAS to have a window to run in, so it's not possible to run as background job. So the "-WindowsStyle hidden" code opens a window that cannot be seen by the user, (but - programatically - is still operational)

It then loops again and again within the "Do" statement to keep the form's Progress Bar running. When the script finshes, the hidden window 'closes', and is removed. This generates an ExitCode of 0. As the "until" is saying "(do the loop) until ExitCode equals 0", the loop is terminated, and the rest of the code executed

Answer (score 0):

The $using variable scope should help here, try something like this

```
$outpath = "C:\test"
$file = "music.mp3"
$saveOut = "saveout"

$jobScript =
{
    #Start-Sleep -Seconds 20
    Write-Output ('$outpath=' + $using:outpath + ' $file=' + $using:file + ' $saveOut=' + $using:saveOut)
}

$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $jobScript -ArgumentList outpath, file, saveout

Get-Job | Receive-Job
```

If you want to know more then run `Get-Help about_scopes`

Answer (score 0):

See also, this article for a good explanation the @jfrmilner is eluding to.

[A Look at Implementing $Using: Support in PowerShell for PoshRSJob](https://learn-powershell.net/2015/05/04/a-look-at-implementing-using-support-in-powershell-for-poshrsjob)

Yet, also consider putting all your arguments in a hash table and passing that. See this article about running executables.

[PowerShell: Running Executables](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)

> Example
> 5. The Call Operator &
>
> Why: Used to treat a string as a SINGLE command. Useful for dealing
> with spaces.
>
> In PowerShell V2.0, if you are running 7z.exe (7-Zip.exe) or another
> command that starts with a number, you have to use the command
> invocation operator &.
>
> The PowerShell V3.0 parser do it now smarter, in this case you don’t
> need the & anymore .
>
> Details: Runs a command, script, or script block. The call operator,
> also known as the "invocation operator," lets you run commands that
> are stored in variables and represented by strings. Because the call
> operator does not parse the command, it cannot interpret command
> parameters

```
& 'C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe' "c:\videos\my home video.avi" /fullscreen
```

> ```
> Things can get tricky when an external command has a lot of parameters or there are spaces in the arguments or paths!
>
> With spaces you have to nest Quotation marks and the result it is not always clear! 
>
> In this case it is better to separate everything like so:
> ```

```
$CMD = 'SuperApp.exe'
$arg1 = 'filename1'
$arg2 = '-someswitch'
$arg3 = 'C:\documents and settings\user\desktop\some other file.txt'
$arg4 = '-yetanotherswitch'
 
& $CMD $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4
```

> or same like that:

```
$AllArgs = @('filename1', '-someswitch', 'C:\documents and settings\user\desktop\some other file.txt', '-yetanotherswitch')
 
& 'SuperApp.exe' $AllArgs
```

Comment: Sincere apologies to everyone who posted answers. I've been working on other (easier) HTML / javascript aspects, and haven't checked back since. I have tried various options to get FFMPEG to run, a few saying it needs console input to run as it runs 'interaactive', and to disable STDIN. In all cases, it starts ... then immediately returns the "Completed" flag (in 1 sec when needs about 15 secs(